# Jenkins builds failing while recording test results

Tags: build, hudson, maven-surefire-plugin

We have Jenkins version 1.494 and Java 6. It is deployed on JBoss server. I was able to build the projects (using Maven 2) earlier but not sure what has changed and I am getting below error after the tests are run and when it tries to record test results. Any thoughts?

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(JLjava/lang/Iterable;)V
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(JLjava/lang/Iterable;)V
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.postExecute(Maven2Builder.java:157)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder$Adapter.postExecute(MavenBuilder.java:334)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor$1MojoIntercepterImpl.callPost(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:170)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:499)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:478)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:185)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:79)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:55)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: what plugins are you using? what are the job parameters?

Comment: In the parent pom.xml we have configured the maven-surefire-plugin( version 2.12) along with maven-compiler-plugin(2.5.1) and maven-resources-plugin(2.6). In the job parameters I am just passing maven clean install command. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you run the build from the command line on the machine?  What does that give you?
I should have asked that earlier... sorry.

Comment: I can run on my local computer without any issues. It is failing via jenkins build configuration. I am wondering some plugin update on Jenkins may be causing this but not sure which one it is.